# Why is the second tick label different from the others?

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform

I know of ["Why doesn't the second x-axis tick label rotate?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69125957/2749397) but I ***think*** it's not related. I may be wrong.

---

I have this, in the IPython console

```
In [1]: from matplotlib.pyplot import subplot
   ...: from pprint import pprint
   ...: 
   ...: ax = subplot()
   ...: pprint([l.get_transform() for l in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()])
   ...: print()
   ...: ax.set_ylim(-205,105)
   ...: pprint([l.get_transform() for l in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()])
   ...: print()
   ...: ax.set_yticks((-200, 0, 100))
   ...: pprint([l.get_transform() for l in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()])
Installed qt5 event loop hook.
[<matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101eaa50>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>]

[<matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101eaa50>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>]

[<matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101eaa50>,
 <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x7f35101ebd90>]

In [2]:
```

As you can see, all the labels have the same transform, at `0x7f35101ebd90`, EXCEPT for the second labels that have the same, different transform at `0x7f35101eaa50`.

I'm just curious if there is a reason to distinguish the second tick label from the others.

---

For your convenience, the code w/o the prompts

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplot
from pprint import pprint

ax = subplot()
pprint([l.get_transform() for l in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()])
print()
ax.set_ylim(-205,105)
pprint([l.get_transform() for l in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()])
print()
ax.set_yticks((-200, 0, 100))
pprint([l.get_transform() for l in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()])
```